# Select random rows from Postgres table weighted towards value in column

Tags: postgresql, random

Users are presented with 2 random items from an `assets` table to vote on.

There is a `votes_count` column in the `assets` table that counts each time users vote.

When choosing the 2 random items, I'd like to weight that more towards a *lower* value in `votes_count`. So items with a *lower* vote count have a *higher* probability of being selected randomly.

How can I do this with Postgres?

I've used various methods for selecting random records (`RAND()`, `TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI()`, `TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM()`), but those don't have the *weighting* that I'm after.

I'm running PostgreSQL 13, FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the following query :

```
SELECT *
FROM assets
ORDER BY random()/power(votes_count,1) DESC
LIMIT 2
```

It orders in a random way the rows of your table while dividing by the votes_count put the lower votes in a better position than the higher votes in the DESC order.
Replacing the 1 power by any real number *n* will increase the probability of selecting the lower votes when *n* > 1, and decrease the probability of selecting the lower votes when 0 < *n* < 1.